# Testing if element is a number or an object in AS3

Tags: json, actionscript-3

I'm using a program to build game levels with Box2D through exported JSON files but am having trouble with certain elements in the JSON file that tend to have multiple formats.

One "body" element for example has the `position` property that consists of an `x` and a `y` value:

```
"position" : 
{
     "x" : 0,
     "y" : 0
 },
```

Then later in the file another element has the `position` property that has no `x` or `y`, only a single number value:

```
"position" : 0,
```

I've tried things akin to `if(element is Number || element is Object)` to no success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can test the `Object.constructor` property:

```
Object(0).constructor == Number // true
Object(0).constructor != Object // true
{x:0, y:0}.constructor == Object // true
{x:0, y:0}.constructor != Number // true
```